# iOS Incompatible Pointer Types (NSMutableDictionary from NSDictionary)

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I'm having an issue where I use nothing but `NSMutableDictionaries` but somewhere in saving/pulling the data from `Core Data` it's turning into an `NSDictionary` that I can't edit.  Here is the code:

View Controller A

```
@property NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary;
@synthesize myDictionary;
myDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];

//Pull dictionary data in IBAction from somewhere else
APPOtherViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
myDictionary = source.otherDictionary; //other dictionary is also NSMutableDictionary

//On a button press, I save this dictionary to a Core Data transformable attribute (using MR_shorthand):
APPMyObject *newObject = [APPMyObject createEntity];
newObject.coreDictionary = myDictionary;
[[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext]saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

I then pull the CD entity in a new view controller based on a set attribute...

ViewControllerB

```
@property NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary;
@synthesize myDictionary;
myDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];

APPMyObject *details = [APPMyObject findFirstByAttribute:@"myName" withValue:myName];
myDictionary = details.coreDictionary;
```

The warning occurs on the very last line, "Incompatible pointer types assigning to '`NSMutableDictionary`*' from '`NSDictionary`*'.  Everything compiles and runs fine, but the warning is there for a reason.

Forgive me if this is fundamental knowledge, but why does saving the dictionary to `Core Data` change it from mutable to immutable?  If I change everything to `NSDictionary` it works fine, but then I can't edit the information and rewrite.

Thank you!

Comment: NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary;;
myDictionary=[myDictionary initWithDictionary:details.coreDictionary]

Comment: myDictionary = (NSMutableDictionary*)details.coreDictionary; use this it will take care of warning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In these case, you can use this instead of `myDictionary = details.coreDictionary;`.

```
myDictionary = [NSMutableDicationary dictionaryWithDictionary:details.coreDictionary];
```

**Updation:**
I saw that `myDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];`, this line totally waste. Even you allocate to NSMutableDictionary, during assign with `details.coreDictionary`, It will try to assign a `NSDictionary` object with `NSMutableDictionary` variable which means, `myDictionary` try to point `NSMutableDictionary` memory which leads to compile time error. Also Type casting to NSMutableDictionary`myDictionary = (NSMutableDictionary*)details.coreDictionary;`, temporary solve your problem but type casting is not correct one. After assign it, when you try to access NSMutable method, it will get crash.

Comment: Thanks!  Can you briefly explain why I had to redefine the NSMutableDictionary?  When I initially save myDictionary to Core Data does it change it to NSDictionary?